# Confusing control flow (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, control-flow

I'm trying to create a game in Ruby involving selecting numbers in a certian order and getting the right sequence in a limited number of tries, blah, blah, blah. My issue is no matter what numbers I guess, it doesn't add to the `@correct_r` variable, nor does it display if it's in the correct position.

I'm almost certian I'm missing an `if`/`else` statement in there somewhere, but not sure where. Any help is appreciated.

Code

```
#by Touka, ©2015
actions = (0..9).to_a
@sequence = []
4.times do |key|
    key = actions.sample
    @sequence << key
end
@fails_left = 10
@correct_a = 0
@correct_r = 0
@a = " "
@b = " "
@c = " "
@d = " "
def sel
    system "cls"
    puts """
    __________________________________
   /   ___     ___     ___     ___    \\
   |  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   |  | #{@a} |   | #{@b} |   | #{@c} |   | #{@d} |   |
   |  |___|   |___|   |___|   |___|   |
   \\__________________________________/

Tries left:                      #{@fails_left}
Correct numbers (in wrong spot): #{@correct_r}

Enter guess (x x x x):"""
    guess = gets.chomp
    guess = guess.split(" ")
    case guess[0]
    when @sequence[0]
        @correct_a += 1
        @a = "#"
    when @sequence[1]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[2]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[3]
        @correct_r += 1
    end
    case guess[1]
    when @sequence[0]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[1]
        @correct_a += 1
        @b = "#"
    when @sequence[2]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[3]
        @correct_r += 1
    end
    case guess[2]
    when @sequence[0]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[1]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[2]
        @correct_a += 1
        @c = "#"
    when @sequence[3]
        @correct_r += 1
    end
    case guess[3]
    when @sequence[0]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[1]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[2]
        @correct_r += 1
    when @sequence[3]
        @correct_a += 1
        @d = "#"
    end
    ct = @correct_r + @correct_a
    if ct == 0
        @fails_left -= 1
    else
        hi = " "
    end
    sel
end
sel
```

Comment: '@' prefix means this is a class instance variable. Why do you use that?

Comment: @megabyde it's a global variable, no?

Comment: global variables are using '$' prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in different types of sequence and guess variables. Sequence is array of integer and guess is array of strings. You need to convert them to same type.

```
guess = guess.map(&:to_i)
```